# Simple read vs write boolean variable performance comparison question

Tags: performance, memory, compiler-construction, boolean

What should be the preferred way by programmers:

1) Only Write:

```
SomeBoolean = True
```

2) Read but write only if necessary

```
If Not SomeBoolean Then SomeBoolean = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to know the answer to this without knowing more about the environment. It seems a reasonable check would be to run some performance tests by iterating over this task many, many times.

Empirical evidence sometimes is surprising compared to what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to a RUNTIME context and a shared variable:

In a multiprocessor environment, unnecessary writes can lead to performance degradation: cache  flush, synchronization overhead etc.

So YES it can make a difference... get profiling **if** the situation lends itself to it.

Comment: So you say I SOULD make the checking?

Comment: Depends on your performance requirements: some might say it is "premature optimization" in cases X,Y,Z whilst in some other cases (e.g. Kernel Drivers) it might be crucial to ascertain the situation.

Comment: One should also remember that a conditional jump might cost more then the assignment itself (if the variable is in the L1 cache and it's not accessed by other threads frequently). So generally I would suggest not doing such an "optimization" unless logic and/or profiling suggests that the caused cache invalidations are a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

The difference is negligible. You will see performance differences when reading and writing files to the drive, but program performance is measured in big O. Read:

[BIG O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation)

Especially in VB you will not see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

1) will be maybe a few nanoseconds faster. I suspect that compared to other things going on in your code, that difference is nanoscopic.

On the other hand, I usually write (2) if I might want to do something else when I know that I'm actually *changing* the boolean. That gives me a place to do it.